# Object Orientating C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a general question for Object Orientating in C#.

Suppose I have multiple XAML pages which all have this method:

```
private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // Do Something
}
```

Now I have a class to hold a method, the class is called Methods.cs and holds this:

```
public void StopUpperAndSpace(TextBox txtBox) 
{
   txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text.Trim();
   // Set it to lowercase
   txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text.ToLower();
}
```

When a user clicks the SubmitButton on any of the pages I want it to perform this method stored in the Methods.cs. If i have a textbox on one XAML page called NameTextBox when a user clicks the SubmitButton how would I perform the method so the NameTextBox in the SubmitButton_Click method is equal to the txtBox in the StopUpperAndSpace method?

I understand the question is hard to understand but Im finding it really hard to explain. If you need clarification, just comment! Thanks:)

Comment: This method can become `static` and then calling it is easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have I misunderstood you, why wouldn't you be able to pass it to your method? I would also make your method a static, but if you wanted to create an instance of your Methods class you technically could.

**SomePage.xaml**

```
<TextBox x:Name="SomeTextBox" />
<TextBox x:Name="SomeOtherTextBox />
```

**SomePage.xaml.cs**

```
private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Your initial method call could potentially look like this.
    Methods.StopUpperAndSpace(this.SomeTextBox);

    // Alternatively you could do something like this.
    this.SomeOtherTextBox.Text = Methods.ToLowerAndTrim(this.SomeOtherTextBox.Text);
}
```

**Methods.cs**

```
public static void StopUpperAndSpace(TextBox txtBox) 
{
    txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text.Trim();
    // Set it to lowercase
    txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text.ToLower();
}

public static string ToLowerAndTrim(string text)
{
    return text.Trim().ToLower();
}
```

Comment: So just to assign the StopUpperAndSpace method to a different textbox in a different XAML page I would just have to do this: Methods.StopUpperAndSpace(this.NameTextBox); Also could you please explain why you would recommend making it static? Thanks:)

Comment: @JermainDefo I'm not sure I understand your first point, but I've expanded on the example hopefully this will make it easier to understand. Regarding the static, I suggested doing this so you can access your method StopUpperAndSpace without creating an instance of your class, i.e., Methods m = new Methods();

Comment: Ahhh okay, thanks for that information! Is it possible to do the same with variables? So if I had functions with variables in the Methods class so like if(variable == 2) { // do something} is it possible to do the same with what you did with TextBoxes but this time with variables?

Comment: @JermainDefo I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Perhaps if you create another question and provide some code myself or someone else will be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry man, its really hard for me to explain. Basically, if I was to do exactly what you did but this time with variables. Is it the same?

Comment: @JermainDefo I'm still not sure I understand your question, but I've added another method to the example perhaps this is where you were headed? If not I think you'll really want to create a new question as this is potentially getting off topic.